# Center input placeholder in Safari on Win7

Tags: html, css, input, safari, placeholder

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9V3f/

I try to center placeholder in my input with such css rule:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}
```

This css works correctly in Chrome but in Safari (Windows 7) input placeholder aligns to left. I tried doing things with relative and absolute positions, margins - nothing seems to work. So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
::input-placeholder
```

is supported on by safari 5+, so depending on which version of safari you have it should work

also you can try

```
input[placeholder]
```

^ works for text align in most browsers

Comment: I'm running my fiddle on safari 5. Your selectors doesn't work too (

Comment: Me too, but under windows, does not